# simple regex_match in VS 2012 not working

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS 2012 C++. The following simple regex_match doesn't ever find what I'm looking for. I've stripped it down to the following. What am I missing?

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int _tmain( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int i = 0;
   auto matches = smatch();
   regex rx( "." );
   string haystack( "ABC." );

   if( regex_match( haystack, matches, rx ) )
      i++;
   if( regex_match( haystack, rx ) )
      i++;
   if( regex_match( haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), rx ) )
      i++;
}
```

`regex_match` always returns false.

Comment: it is because "." (dot) have special meaning in regex syntax, it will match all character, you will need to escape that using "\" (slash) like "\.", do some research you will get it.

Comment: Yes, I understand; thanks. I wasn't looking for the actual dot. In my frustration I wanted to see if it would match anything. stribizhev has the answer...RTFM (and he was nice enough not to say it that way!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

> Note that regex_match will only successfully match a regular
>   expression to an entire character sequence, whereas std::regex_search
>   will successfully match subsequences.

Thus, this code will find the matches:

```
if( regex_search( haystack, matches, rx ) )
   i++;
if( regex_search( haystack, rx ) )
   i++;
if( regex_search( haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), rx ) )
   i++;
```